# Subsequent convolution layers

Tags: neural-network, convolution, convolutional-neural-network

*Note: I've read [How do subsequent convolution layers work?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/how-do-subsequent-convolution-layers-work) a few times, but it's still difficult to understand because of the parameters $k_1$, $k_2$, and many proposals (1, 2.1, 2.2) in the question. This seems to be complex for other people too, I think I'm not the only one (see a few comments like "I have just struggled with this same question for a few hours"). So here it is formulated with a particular specific example with no parameters, to grasp the idea more easily.*

Let's say we have a CNN with:

- input: 28x28x1 grayscale images (28x28 pixels, 1 channel)
- 1st convolutional layer with kernel size 3x3, and 32 features
- 2nd convolutional layer with kernel size 3x3, and 64 features

Keras implementation:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

**Question: how does the 2nd layer work?**

More precisely:

- for the 1st layer:

  - input size: (1, 28, 28, 1)
  - weights size: (3, 3, 1, 32)  (good to know: the number of weights doesn't depend on input pixel size)
  - output size: (1, 26, 26, 32)
- for the 2nd layer:

  - input size: (1, 26, 26, 32)
  - weights size: (3, 3, <strike>1</strike> 32, 64)
  - **output size: (1, 24, 24, 64)**

How is the latter possible? It seemed to me that, in the 2nd layer, every input 26x26 image will be convolved with the 3x3 kernels of each 64 feature maps, **but this could done for all the 32 channels!**

Thus I had the feeling the output of 2nd layer should be (1, 24, 24, 32*64)

**How does it work here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the reason: the correct description of the 2nd layer is:

- for the 2nd layer:

  - input size: (1, 26, 26, 32)
  - weights size: (3, 3, **32**, 64)
  - output size: (1, 24, 24, 64)

So for each one of the 64 features, the (26,26,32) input is convoled with a (3,3,**32**)-sized kernel, producing a (24,24) output.

Since this is for each one of the 64 features, the output will finally be (1, 24, 24, 64).

---

Code to display the shape of the weights:

```
for l in model.layers:
    if len(l.get_weights()) > 0:
        print(l.get_weights()[0].shape)        # ...[1].shape  would be for the biases
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit.  The input has 3 channels.  The filter size is 5x5.  No bias for each filter.

```
model = Sequential([
    Convolution2D(32, 5, activation='relu', use_bias=False, input_shape=(28, 28, 3),),
    Convolution2D(64, 5, activation='relu', use_bias=False,),
])

model.summary()
```

The output is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 32)        2400      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 20, 20, 64)        51200     
=================================================================
Total params: 53,600
Trainable params: 53,600
Non-trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Notice that the output of the first layer has only 32 channels (32 feature maps) not 32x3 channels.  This is because each filter is not a 2D filter.  It is 3D!  For the first layer, each filter has 5x5x3 weights. Therefore the total weights for the first layer is 5x5x3x32=2400 weights.

For the second layer, each filter has 5x5x32 weights.  Therefore the total weights for the first layer is 5x5x32x64=51200 weights.